# Install pandas package in offline unix machine

Tags: python, pandas, unix

I have installed python 2.7.15 in unix machine using tarball file, I want to install pandas library in this machine, but this machine is offline, so I cannot use pip (couldnt install PIP), is there a method to download pandas package for unix from internet and install into this unix offline machine. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can. In a nutshell, you can download the package manually and than install the package. This what is happening when you use the `pip install` command.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for response, could you please elaborate further, I am sorry I did not understand nutshell stuff... it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply and thanks again for response but I couldn't able to install PIP(downloaded get_pip.py and trying to run with python get_pip.py getting hashlib ssh256 not found errors), will give more details regarding that shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I am elaborating my comment.
Yes you can.

1. Go to `pypi` repository and look for the relevant package, in your case [pandas 0.24](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/0.24.0/), due to the fact it is the last version which support python 2.x
2. Download the relevant package from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/0.24.0/#files). You need to install the one that compatible with unix.
3. Once download, copy the Wheel file (python installation file for packages) path. lets say `/home/pandas.wheel`
4. run: `pip install /home/pandas.wheel`